# Need help in looping

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've range of data, and I want to loop the range 52 times and after completing one loop it should add 7 with date last used,

Something like this :-
[image]

I have demonstrated it 2 times, but I want to do it 52 times or n number of times.
Need help in figuring out how I can do this, either by formula or script!

Comment: The question needs more focus (choose one formula or script, you might ask for the other in another post), show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a script for this, it should repeat the range n number of times with dates incrementing by 7 days. Please take a look at the nested `for` loop for the manipulation of the 2D array.

```
function dateFill() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // constants
  var numOfIteration = 52;
  var DAY_IN_MS = 1000*60*60*24;
  var nameArray = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];

  var newArray = [];
  var startDate = new Date(sheet.getRange("B1").getValue());
  
  for (i = 0; i < numOfIteration; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date();
    newDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() + 7*i*DAY_IN_MS);
    for (j = 0; j < nameArray.length; j++) {
      newArray.push([nameArray[j], newDate]);
    }
  }

  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var writeRange = sheet.getRange(lr+1,1,nameArray.length * numOfIteration,2);
  writeRange.setValues(newArray);

}
```

Sample:

[image]